# Logback: Exception when the file grows beyond maxFileSize

Tags: logback, slf4j

I have below rolling policy in  the logback.xml.
       Problem is, if file size grows beyond 10 MB , it's throwing exception.
Looks like it is trying to create a new file but since the same file is already present for the same date, it's not able to do that and throws exception.
For example , we already have a file pvExport.2016-05-15.log and if pvExport.log grows beyond 10 MB, it would try to create the file with the same name as pvExport.2016-05-15.log, and hence would throw exception, not sure though

```
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${EXPORT_LOG_HOME}/pvExport.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
                        </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `fileNamePattern` is actually invalid in this case. From the [docs](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy)

> Note the "%i" conversion token in addition to "%d". Both the %i and %d tokens are mandatory. Each time the current log file reaches maxFileSize before the current time period ends, it will be archived with an increasing index, starting at 0.

Adding the `%i` conversion token to your pattern should fix this:

```
<fileNamePattern>${EXPORT_LOG_HOME}/pvExport.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
```